# Sending Email with mp4 attachment does not work

Tags: android, email

I use the following code to send an email with an mp4 attachment:

```
           Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.setType("*/mp4");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            File f = new File(record[ipos]);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Select Email Client"));
```

The values of `f` and `uri` equals:

```
f = {java.io.File@830047473992} "data/data/com.example.bernard.speechparole/files/5-auth.mp4"
uri = {android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri@830047488248} "file:///data/data/com.example.bernard.speechparole/files/5-auth.mp4"
```

I select the yahoo client:
It shows up in the client (yahoo) with the right file attached with a file size. Everything works as fine, but I never receive the email (I've checked the spam folder). When I send the email without the attachment (I remove the attachment from the client), all works fine and I receive the email.

I select the Gmail client:
The email shows up with the proper attachment file name but no file size.
I get a "couldn't send attachment". I receive the email with no attachment.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I should have written the last sentence as follows: I select the gmail client: the email shows up in the GUI with the proper attachment file name but no file size. I get a "couldn't send attachment" on my android device. I receive the email with no attachment in my inbox.

Comment: You should send a file from external memory as other apps have no access to your app's private memory. Or use a content provider.

Comment: Thanks! I want to keep the internal storage model. So I need to do read internal file/write to the external storage. do you agree? there is no copy function?

Comment: A copy fuction is a simple piece of code which has been published on this site many times. Just google android copyfile